# How do I collect a single column content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I collect a single column content

```html
<td class="checkallprice">300</td>
<td class="checkallprice">110</td>
<td class="checkallprice">350</td>
<td class="checkallprice">100</td>
<td class="checkallprice">I need Total Here</td>
```

Comment: Show us the complete table instead of `td`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `.each` to iterate `td` elements
- Select last `td` using `:last-child` selector
- Use `:not(:last-child)` to exclude `last-child`
- Use `Number` to cast `string` to `number`

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(this).find('td:not(:last-child)').each(function() {
    sum += Number(this.textContent);
  });
  $(this).find(':last-child').text(sum);
})
```

```css
td:last-child {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkallprice">300</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">110</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">350</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">100</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">I need Total Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkallprice">10</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">120</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">30</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">40</td>
    <td class="checkallprice">I need Total Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, `calculateTotal()` will calculate the total of all the previous siblings. And `$('.checkallprice').last()` will find the last element and set the text to the result from `calculateTotal()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function calculateTotal() {
         var total = 0;
       jQuery(this).prevAll().each(function() {
            total += Number(jQuery(this).text());
       });
       return total;
    }
    $('.checkallprice').last().text(calculateTotal);
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mh5gn7zx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Get the `html` of every `td` except the last one, parse them to `Int/Float` and add them up.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var sum=0;
  $('table tr td').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':last-child'))
    {
      $(this).html(sum);
    } 
    else
    {
      sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).html());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
<td class="checkallprice">300</td>
<td class="checkallprice">110</td>
<td class="checkallprice">350</td>
<td class="checkallprice">100</td>
<td class="checkallprice">I need Total Here</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var sum=0;
  $('table tr td').not('td:last').each(function(){//select all the td except the last
      sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).text());//sum the values
  });
   $('table tr td:last').text(sum);//append to the last one
});
```

or if you have multiple `tr`

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var sum=0;
 $('tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('td').not('td:last').each(function(){//select all the td except the last
          sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).text());//sum the values
      });
       $(this).find('td:last').text(sum);//append to the last one
    });
});
```