# Issue in summing the values of td

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few tds ..I need to get the values from each of them and then need to total it.The error which i am facing = Cannot read property 'innerText' of null.

I want solve this problem without jquery..(only using javascript)

Html code;

```
<td id="price1">300</td>
<td id="price2">110</td>
<td id="price3">350</td>
<td id="price4">100</td>
<td id="total">I need Total Here</td>
```

Js code;

```
var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price1").innerText);
var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price2").innerText);
var price3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price3").innerText);
var price4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price4").innerText);
var total = (price1+price2+price3+price4);

document.getElementById("total").innerHtml = total;
```

Error;

```
Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLt05aq9/)

PS:I am a self-taught programmer.I am very new to Javascript.Excuse me for any grammar mistakes,wrongly formatted code,some silly,stupid mistake which i have done.

Thanks in advance,
Sangamesh

Comment: It is an duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451362/how-do-i-collect-a-single-column-content/37451529#37451529

Comment: why you don't use `document.getElementById("price1").innerHTML` ?

Comment: @Rayon In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451362/how-do-i-collect-a-single-column-content/37451529#37451529.They have used jquery to solve the problem..I want the solution in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the page is loaded so use **[`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)**. Also the html markup is not correct missing `table` and `tr`, `td` element should be the child of `tr`. And set the last cell value using `innerText`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price1").innerText);
  var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price2").innerText);
  var price3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price3").innerText);
  var price4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price4").innerText);
  var total = (price1 + price2 + price3 + price4);

  document.getElementById("total").innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="price1">300</td>
    <td id="price2">110</td>
    <td id="price3">350</td>
    <td id="price4">100</td>
    <td id="total">I need Total Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You have invalid markup. `td` elements must be wrapped in `tr` and `tr` in `table`(And that is causing *`Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`*)
- Use `innerText` to assign `total` value(`.innerHTML` will work as well)
- Note: Use `.textContent` instead of `innerText` as `innerText` is [**Non-standard**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property.

```js
var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price1").textContent);
var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price2").textContent);
var price3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price3").textContent);
var price4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price4").textContent);
var total = (price1 + price2 + price3 + price4);
document.getElementById("total").textContent = total; //innerHTML will work as well!
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="price1">300</td>
    <td id="price2">110</td>
    <td id="price3">350</td>
    <td id="price4">100</td>
    <td id="total">I need Total Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.onload`, `.textContent`, `+=` operator at `.innerHTML` to concatenate `total` to existing `html`

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price1").textContent);
var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price2").textContent);
var price3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price3").textContent);
var price4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price4").textContent);
var total = (price1+price2+price3+price4);

document.getElementById("total").innerHTML += " " + total;
}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td id="price1">300</td>
<td id="price2">110</td>
<td id="price3">350</td>
<td id="price4">100</td>
<td id="total">I need Total Here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to open and close table and tr tags outside your td html. Same as below code. The innerHtml should be innerHTML.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="price1">300</td>
<td id="price2">110</td>
<td id="price3">350</td>
<td id="price4">100</td>
<td id="total">I need Total Here</td>
</tr>
</table>


var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price1").innerText);
var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price2").innerText);
var price3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price3").innerText);
var price4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price4").innerText);
var total = (price1+price2+price3+price4);

alert(total);
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: Closing tags for tr and td are optional. ;-)

Comment: you will not be able to get td innerHTML if you do not follow proper table structure in all the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your **td** is not reachable unless it is wrapped inside table and row as **table** > **tr** > **td**.

Complete code being (check fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yLt05aq9/3/))

```
var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price1").innerHTML, 10);
var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price2").innerHTML, 10);
var price3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price3").innerHTML, 10);
var price4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price4").innerHTML, 10);
var total = (price1+price2+price3+price4);

document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```